# Java ME platform SDK 8.2 vs 3.4

Tags: java, java-me

I am try to learn `Java ME`,
So i downloaded and installed the `Java ME SDK 8.2` from [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/javame/javame-sdk/overview/index.html), 
and when i tried to create a new `Mobile Application` it did not detect the `Emulator Platform`,
And when i tried installing the `SDK 3.4` version, i got the emulators.

So my question is, why does the 3.4 version contains the emulator, and the 8.2 doesn't? or are they completely different?